# Do korean webstrips also count as manga?

Tags: support

Are questions about korean webstrips such as [This one](http://www.mangahere.com/manga/magician/) also counted as manga?
And are questions about those also allowed here ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. As per [this meta discussion](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/415/should-we-expand-our-scope), we are expanding out scope to include anime-like and manga-like media such as Korean webtoons.