# Is UnOrdinary on-topic?

Tags: discussion, acceptable-questions

I've been asked a couple times on the Maid Cafe if [*UnOrdinary*](https://www.webtoons.com/en/super-hero/unordinary/list?title_no=679) is on-topic and thought to get more of a consensus than just making the decision myself

### Why it would be on-topic

- it has the "anime/manga style"
- the [Author](https://unordinary.fandom.com/wiki/Uru-chan) is asian in appearance
- it is on LINE WEBTOON which was launched by Naver Corporation who are based in Seongnam, South Korea

### Why it would not be on-topic

- only in english
- not mentioned as being manga or manhwa

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/448/do-korean-webstrips-also-count-as-manga

Answer (score 2):

I do think that UnOrdinary is on topic. If we look at Avatar The Last Airbender and its sequel, Legend of Korra, we see that these are on topic. Not because it was made in Japan but because of how it looks. The same thing with UnOrdinary. So I believe that it counts as on topic.