# Is the tag wiki for [merchandise] correct?

Tags: discussion, tags, allowed-topics

The tag wiki excerpt for [merchandise](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/merchandise) currently reads as follows:

> For questions about anime/manga merchandise. Note that shopping questions (e.g. "Where can I buy this?") are not allowed.

Is the second sentence (no "shopping questions"<sup>1</sup>) a reflection of current community consensus?

I ask because the discussion at [How should we deal with questions asking for where to buy, watch, anime or manga media or such related merchandise?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/595/how-should-we-deal-with-questions-asking-for-where-to-buy-watch-anime-or-manga), occurring in June 2013, asked by a moderator (Krazer), has [an accepted answer](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/596/1908) that suggests that questions about where to procure officially-licensed merchandise are on-topic. This discussion postdates the most recent edit of the tag wiki for [merchandise](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/merchandise), which was on April 18, 2013.

---

<sup>1</sup> The sense in which "shopping question" is being used here is not the same sense in which "shopping question" is used [on the rest of StackExchange](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). In the event that we retain the prohibition on questions about where to purchase things, I recommend that the tag wiki be reworded somehow to avoid the use of the phrase "shopping question".

Answer (score 2):

I've edited the language of the tag in question to note the "shopping recommendations" questions are considered off-topic.