# Song ID from a Japanese game is on topic?

Tags: discussion

I flagged this post as offtopic:

[Song Identification Request, Touhou?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/26144/song-identification-request-touhou)

It was simple to me since Touhou is not anime or manga that this does not belong in the Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. The flag was denied so I'd like clarification on this. Japanese games are on-topic here?

Another question I had was about the current featured/bounty question: [Database of legal sites that allow the download of Anime Soundtracks?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/9611/database-of-legal-sites-that-allow-the-download-of-anime-soundtracks)

Surely this question shouldn't be allowed here as it's sure to attract opinionated answers and doesn't really have a clear concise "answer" that can be given. It doesn't seem to fit the bill of what stack exchange is really about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in [this meta](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/418/63) games (and aspect related) are on topic (to an extent). This is in an extension of our policy allowing story questions about visual novels with some gameplay elements. Touhou media [exists](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/subcultures/touhou-project-%E6%9D%B1%E6%96%B9project#fanbase) outside of their respective games and in anime and manga subculture as well, so discussions come up often when discussing anime and manga.
On this site we try not to be too restrictive with question that are related to anime and manga subculture and try to encourage discussion of them along with related media, including derivative and anime-like media such as *RWBY* and *Avatar: The Last Airbender*.

As for the bounties question asking for resources to purchase anime music, it's a legitimate resource request as it's often times difficult to find legal sources to purchase anime music.

While there might not conclusive answer, users can give suggestions as to their favorite sites in an objective way, such as explaining what one site has to offer over another.

Resource list do exist in many Stack Exchanges as a means to better compile useful sites and service in an easily searchable and readable format

Here are some examples from other Stack Exchanges:

- https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2889/resources-for-learning-chemistry
- https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/833/resources-for-learning-russian
- https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/resources-for-learning-german
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides
- https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261/online-legal-references

If you believe that an answer in a resource list is inadequate, inaccurate, or downright misleading feel free to make a comment to let other users know and downvote the answer accordingly.

If you feel up to the challenge, you can also try your hand at writing an answer. Good resource list can help a lot of people out by providing information in an easy to read for mat. Maintenance of these list can take some work, but bounties are there to encourage users to participate.