# Can I ask about other things related to anime & manga?

Tags: discussion

Like in the title said can I ask question other than anime and manga. Like can I ask about Manhwa, Manhua, or Chinese or Korean novels.

Comment: Questions about Manhwa, Manhua and Chinese or Korean **light/visual** novels are permitted, though our focus is of course on anime and manga. This question belongs on [meta], which you could ask when you have enough reputation (5, I think), but you needn't since I just answered it.

Comment: http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2535/what-topics-outside-of-anime-and-manga-can-i-ask-about

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in [Should we expand our scope](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/418/1458):

> I tend to see anime and manga more as a culture, at least in the West. There are lots of games, manga-style comics (including manhwa and manhua), and anime-style cartoons which are targeted at, and are just as popular as, the average anime/manga series, and it's strange to not be able to discuss them here. That isn't to say that we're expanding our scope to include Star Trek, even though Star Trek probably is popular among manga fans. But we're including things that would be natural to discuss on an anime-themed site. What exactly those are is up for debate.

So yes, in general questions regarding Manhua, Manwha and even VN related questions can be on-topic. All though, they will most likely be judged by a case on case basis.

In the post mentioned above you can read quite a bit about this. And even though the answer has not yet been accepted, this is the generally consented answer.